# Jdbc connection time-out

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

After getting many concurrent requests JDBC gives timeout & doesn't process any more requests.

Below is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1.getNextValue(TableGenerator.java:530)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.generate(TableGenerator.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.com.ihealthmantra.customer.upload.service.SellerUploadImpl.lambda$4(SellerUploadImpl.java:801)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.com.ihealthmantra.customer.upload.service.SellerUploadImpl.createTimeSlotUploadedSeller(SellerUploadImpl.java:738)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.com.ihealthmantra.customer.upload.service.SellerUploadImpl.populateSlot(SellerUploadImpl.java:1146)
    at com.ihealthmantra.upload.App.main(App.java:81)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 820,677 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 820,679 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
.....
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My queries are heavy and they take time to process so I have solved the issue by configuring a few values like:

1. Increasing `maximumPoolSize` to increase concurrent request handling.
2. Increasing `connectionTimeout` so that requests will wait a little longer before timing out.

You can change these configs by adding the following values in application.properties. (The values that worked for me might not work for you as well so you need to test different values as per your use case)

```
{datasource}.maximumPoolSize=100 
{datasource}.connectionTimeout=60000
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how and where you made these changes? And what documentation you may have referred to? Anything which will make this answer more helpful for future visitors to your question.

Comment: @andrewJames You can increase default values using application properties. The values that worked for me might not work for you as well so you need to test different values as per your use case.

`{datasource}.maximumPoolSize=100
{datasource}.connectionTimeout=60000`

Comment: Please be more specific and precise. Please add the relevant info to the answer ( not a comment). This is not for me - it is for future visitors who read your answer.